# Accessing pointer to data member using macro results in "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘*’ token"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, macros, c-preprocessor, pointer-to-member

Minimal code of the bigger problem:

```
struct S { int i; };
typedef int (S::*Type);

Type foo (int) { return &S::i; }
#define FOO(X) *foo(X)

int main ()
{
  S s;
  s.*foo(0) = 0; // ok
  s.FOO(0) = 0; // error  <--- ?? 
}
```

If `foo()` method is replaced with `FOO()` macro to avoid '*', then it results in the error posted in title. When I checked the preprocessing using `g++ -E` option, then both the "ok" & "error" lines look same.
Why is this error with macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *clang 3.8* I got the next output for your program:

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 325 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "test.cpp" 2
struct S { int i; };
typedef int (S::*Type);

Type foo (int) { return &S::i; }


int main ()
{
  S s;
  s.*foo(0) = 0;
  s. *foo(0) = 0;
}
```

One can see the space in the line:

```
s. *foo(0) = 0;
```

This space is the reason for "expected the unqualified-id before..." error. The space itself should be a product of [token spacing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Token-Spacing.html).

I do not know why *g++* does not show the space. Possibly it's a compiler bug concerning representing the output of preprocessing.

Comment: Your analysis seems correct to me. It's more of gcc bug.